# Querying by UserID with Google Analytics Data API

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to query Google Analytics Data APIs with user_id as a parameter? I am asking this prior to implementation since I can't find anything in the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/s/results/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1?q=user_id&text=user_id) about it.

For example I want to run a query that will return

- Session history for a specific user ID
- Count the number of customer custom events triggered by a specific user

Answer (score 1):

You can create audiences for different groups of session history & counts of those custom events. Then, you can export those audiences using the [Audience Lists API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1alpha/properties.audienceLists/create).

`userId` is a dimension that can be used in the Audience List API; this page shows the [schema for the Audience List API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/audience-list-api-schema).

This doc provides an introduction with [examples for the Audience List API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/audience-list-basics).